# some extra characters get added to the argument passed to the function

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am calling a function  parse_consol(definition1); where the definition i.e the argument passed is of char* type and is absolute path of the xml file. when I check the (by debugging) the value being passed is absoultely correct but when the control to the definition of the function the value which it is taking gets appended with some random characters at the end and this results in failure.

I need to know how these characters got appended at the end to the actual argument in the definition of the function.

Code from comment below:

```
definition_state1 = (char*)malloc(((int) strlen(((char*)definition_path)+1))); 
strcpy(definition_state1 ,(char*)definition_path); 
definition_state2 = (char*)malloc(((int) strlen(((char*)value[1])+1))); 
strcpy(definition_state2 ,(char*)value[1]); 
strcat(definition_state1,definition_state2); 
get_license_properties("D:\\Automation\\InputFiles\\current_state\\c2v1.c2v"); // parser for decoded c2v 
parse_consolidated(definition_state1); // parser for consolidated xm
```

Comment: show us the code..most probably you are missing a null terminator.

Comment: definition_state1 = (char*)malloc(((int) strlen(((char*)definition_path)+1))); strcpy(definition_state1 ,(char*)definition_path); definition_state2 = (char*)malloc(((int) strlen(((char*)value[1])+1))); strcpy(definition_state2 ,(char*)value[1]); strcat(definition_state1,definition_state2); get_license_properties("D:\\Automation\\InputFiles\\current_state\\c2v1.c2v"); // parser for decoded c2v parse_consolidated(definition_state1); // parser for consolidated xml

Comment: What's up with all those casts?

Comment: The value returned by `malloc` need not be cast in C. And in fact, shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you are overflowing `definition_state1` buffer. You allocated `definition_path+1` buffer and copied `definition_path` in to the buffer. Then you are appending `definition_state2` to this buffer which will surely overflow the `definition_state1` buffer.